# URLSession For Flask API not entering session

Tags: swift, xcode, api, flask

Hey I have this Flask api that im running locally for right now and this is the code that is supposed to grab the words from the API but for some reason it does not enter the `do {` block.
The URL is correct. Can I not call an API that i am locally running or am I just doing something wrong? Do I have to use Alamofire?

```
func setWords() -> [Word]{ 
var words = [Word]()
guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/words/all")
else
{
    print("BAD URL in Words.swift")
    return words
} //empty

let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        if let respond = json.values.first {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(respond)
                words = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Word].self, from: respond as! Data)
            }
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Words.swift Error in try catch")
    }
})
task.resume()
return words
```

}

Comment: I assume you're running in the simulator? What is printing to the console? Note that your function will always return an empty array.

Comment: @Don yes I'm running this in the XCode simulator. There is no output in either the XCode console or the console for the API server (so it never even calls upon the api). I have determined that it skips the `do{` statement by using breakpoints so there is no way for it to `print(respond)` anyways. Why would it always be empty? Wouldn't `words = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Word].self, from: respond as! Data)` populate the words. Even if its not, the bigger problem here is that it never enters the `do{`. Any suggestions?